# Phonegap:- Snapchat Authentication Implementation

Tags: phonegap-plugins, snapchat

I'm working on a project which will use SnapChat authentication in my PhoneGap app. I looked around in the SnapChat API documentation, but i couldn’t find anything about this subject.

So my question is, is there any plugin or API available to authenticate through SnapChat in a PhoneGap application? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there’s no legal way to authenticate through SnapChat at the moment. They neither expose APIs nor some authentication flow.